# sssd using remote ad servers instead of local ad servers

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, rhel6, sssd, rhel7

I am using sssd to join Redhat servers to a windows server 2008 r2 domain. Most of the time things work fine but I have noticed that sssd is trying to reach remote domain servers instead of being aware of the local domain servers and just using them for authentication. This creates a problem because the firewall blocks these attempts. Any idea what setting I am missing in order to make the Linux boxes just look locally for authentication. I am aware of the ad_server setting but would prefer to not set this if sssd is able to be aware of the local servers.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant configuration files to the body of your question, as well as some diagnostics you might have performed, relevant logs, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using service discovery, then your hosts will query any DC in your domain.

If you want to specify which DC's your hosts use for auth, you need to do so in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

From the sssd-ad man page:

```
ad_server, ad_backup_server (string)
The comma-separated list of IP addresses or hostnames of the AD servers
to which SSSD should connect in order of preference. For more information
on failover and server redundancy, see the "FAILOVER" section. This is
optional if autodiscovery is enabled. For more information
on service discovery, refer to the "SERVICE DISCOVERY" section.
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have read the man pages but sssd is site aware and in this case is pulling not only DCs from other sites but desktop computers as domain controllers. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't aware sssd is now site-aware. The next thing i would try is to enable DNS query logging on the DCs that are in your host's /etc/resolv.conf. Then you can track what DNS _SRV queries your host is requesting and what answers it is receiving.